# Story where refugees get attacked by space pirates?

Tags: story-identification

I remember that it was a family fleeing a horticulture moon or a planet and they were trying to flee to another planet but were repeatedly attacked by pirates.

I think it was from the 80's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "refugees constantly attacked every other chapter" matches very well with "Refugee" (book 1 of  Piers Anthony's "[Bio of a Space Tyrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bio_of_a_Space_Tyrant)" series).

Comment: This is also covered in book 6: Iron Maiden.